# Change font in baposter package

Tags: fonts, luatex, baposter

I tried to change the font to garamond in baposter.cls using the following code:

```
\usepackage{bm}  % bold stuff 
\usepackage{bbm} % bold stuff
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[
 Path           = garamond/,
 BoldFont       = Garamond.ttf,
 ItalicFont     = GARAIT.TTF,
 BoldItalicFont = garmndmi.ttf]
 {GARAM.ttf}
\setmonofont[
 Scale          = 0.9,
 Path           = garamond/,
 BoldFont       = Garamond.ttf,
 ItalicFont     = GARAIT.ttf,
 BoldItalicFont = garmndmi.ttf]
 {GARAM.ttf}
```

I got the fonts from [here](https://www.wfonts.com/font/garamond). I am not sure what I am doing wrong since I am new to baposter.

Comment: Don't load `fontenc` when using LuaTeX or XeTeX. You shouldn't have to load the fonts manually, the `ebgaramond` package should find them.  Let the package do the work.

Comment: The fonts should be part of your TeX distribution (or if not, they can be installed by it).

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ebgaramond` fonts are part of TeX Live, and will be found simply by loading the `ebgaramond` package. You should not load the `fontenc` package when using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX; just load `fontspec`.